# Windows Batch to automatically unmap Network Drive on Wifi?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, batch, script

I have number of network drives for work. When I work from home, my computer is very slow due to these network drives trying to connect. Does anyone know of a script, which will automatically unmap these drives when I am on a specific wifi network (and possibly map when I am back at work)?

I have a batch file that can do the unmapping as follows:

`net use Q: /delete`

I want to automate it based on the network. Can someone please help or suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if I knew your SSID but here is a script that will do it for you. It will wait 30 seconds before starting so you can set the batch file to run on startup.

```
@Echo off

timeout 30 /nobreak

rem Name of fictitious work wireless SSID is "Office Wireless"
:Find
for /f "tokens=1,3,4" %%a in ('netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr "SSID"') Do (
If %%a EQU BSSID GOTO Next
set VAR1=%%b
set VAR2=%%c
)

:Next
Set SSID=%VAR1% %VAR2%
Echo Current Wireless Network: %SSID%

If %SSID% EQU "Office Wireless" (
                              net use Q: \\Server1\Share /persistent:no
                              net use T: \\Server2\Share /persistent:no
                              ) ELSE (
                                      net use Q: /delete
                                      net use T: /delete
                                      )
```